# Two list in a function with minimum execution with n number of lists in python

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a n number of lists, Now I want to calculate the similarity of n lists with a list called l.

Now I am using following code,

```
from scipy import spatial
similarity_score=[]
for i in n:
    spatial.similarity_score.append(spatial.distance.cosine(i,l))
```

Now It gives the result I wanted, but the execution time is huge, looking for some alternative process where the same thing could be done in least execution time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create this in a parallel way with for instance numpy

Say you data in in the format

```
#
# X contained 1000 lists of size 50
#
import numpy as np

X = np.random.random( (50,1000) )

#
# v contains the vector you want to calculate the distance to
#

v = np.random.random( (50,1) )
```

Than the loop approach is

```
%%timeit
#
# for loop approach
#

from scipy import spatial

similarity_score=[]

for i in X.T:
    similarity_score.append(spatial.distance.cosine(i,v))
```

Which on my machine gave

```
82.3 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And produces the following output

```
similarity_score[:10]

[0.22282765699585905,
 0.2160367009172488,
 0.30853097430098786,
 0.24034072729579192,
 0.16217833767527134,
 0.2829791739176786,
 0.18946375557860284,
 0.19624968983011593,
 0.2484078232716126,
 0.3258394812037617]
```

When we implement this parallel in numpy

```
%%timeit
#
# Parallel approach using np.einsum
#


I = np.einsum("ij,ij->j", X,v)
D = 1 - I / ( np.linalg.norm(X,ord=2,axis=0) * np.linalg.norm(v,ord=2,axis=0) )
```

We get

```
191 µs ± 63.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And of course check output

```
D[:10]


array([0.22282766, 0.2160367 , 0.30853097, 0.24034073, 0.16217834,
       0.28297917, 0.18946376, 0.19624969, 0.24840782, 0.32583948])
```

Note the output of the example is not of the same type, `numpy` will output a `numpy` array.